# Memory usage keeps growing at message reception

Tags: c++, memory, boost-asio

I'm using the library `boost.asio` to create a server application.
Everything looks fine but when I tried some tests on it, I found that the memory usage is growing when it's receiving the message.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  // IOService : 
  boost::asio::io_service ios;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 9000));
  tcp::socket s(ios);

  acceptor.accept(s);

  while(true){

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)); // Some rest for the CPU
    int available = s.available();
    if(!available) // If there are no bytes available we jump to the next iteration
      continue;
    std::vector<char> buffer(s.available());
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::read(s, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), boost::asio::transfer_all(), ec);
    if(!ec){
      std::string s(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;

}
```

[EDIT 2] :

```
// Buffer outside the loop:
//No sleep
Start : 188K
Max :12112K
End :8620K

//Sleep 500ms
Start : 188K
Max : 12048k
End : 12048k

//Sleep 100ms
Start : 192K
Max : 12060k
End : 6524k

//Buffer inside the loop

// No sleep
Start : 188K
Max :  11936K
End :  2128k


//Sleep 100ms
Start : 188k
Max : 11936k
End : 584k


//Sleep 500ms
Start : 188k
Max : 11932k
End : 1112k
```

Thanks.

[EDIT] If you have any good tools under linux to measure memory usage that would be nice (I know `valgrind` but I'm only using it for memory leak checks)

Comment: Maybe a fragmentation issue ?

Comment: That's interesting ! I didn't know about this kind of issues :) Any way to solve it ?

Comment: Avoid allocation/deallocation in the loop (so moving `buffer` and `s` outside of the loop, that way, they may reuse there memory as long as the new size is less than there current capacity), or use a custom allocator (which allocates by block to reduce fragmentation).

Comment: What is the question?  Also, can you please provide the data you used to deduce that memory usage keeps growing at message reception?  I was not able to observe continuous growth in [`/proc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) filesystem with 100,000 iterations of sending a constant data size, then 10,000 more iterations with the data size doubled.

Comment: @Tanner: Here is my test client : http://pastebin.com/9369F2Dk and I edited the post to add some measurements

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure how to deduce that memory usage keeps growing at message reception from that data.  Memory growth will occur in kernel allocated memory if the socket data is being consumed at slower rate than it is being produced.  However, I was not been able to observe continuous memory growth in the application with the test client.